# iPad Kiosk application // Guided Access and empty Battery

Tags: ios, ipad, kiosk, kiosk-mode, guided-access

We want to use iPads with iOS7 for an POS/Kiosk application. We use the guided access mode to restrict the customers to one app. The store will shut down the power during weekends, so the iPads will run out of battery. This raises several questions:

1. Is there a way to send an ipad to sleep mode and awake them programmatically? So that the iPad battery might last a complete weekend without power?
2. What will happen when the power resumes, if the ipad blacked out?
3. Will the last run app be resumed in guided access mode?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for your help!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable access to the hardware buttons. I've never had problems with people turning off the device during the business day.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after quite some time I can give an update on this. The way we used in the end was a MDM solution (mobile device management). We had less then 100 devices to manage, so we use the free version of meraki (https://meraki.cisco.com/). Which is an awesome tool. With Meraki you are able to remotely to install certificates, that lock the iPad completely.

In a way, that if you don't have Wifi / Internet on the iPads, you cannot remove the lock, without resetting the iPad completely.

Coming back to the original question, the iPads run on battery until they die in the morning. And they are charged throughout the day. So it's a complete load / discharge cycle everyday. Since there is no way of changing this, we stopped to deploy iPads for POS in-store projects and switched to Android devices like without battery.

Hope this helps someone!